# if and sumifs with multiple named range critera and a between (<>) array with data pull down from a system

Tags: arrays, database, excel, sumifs

I am working on a formula that needs to sum the total value based upon 
three criteria.

The formula as follows works:

```
=IF($D$4<=4,IF($D$4=1,SUMIFS(Name1,Nmd1,189,Nmd2,'Spreadsheet'!$A75),IF($D$4=2,SUMIFS(Name2,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),IF($D$4=3,SUMIFS(Name3,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),SUMIFS(Name4,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75)))),IF($D$4<=8,IF($D$4=5,SUMIFS(Name5,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),IF($D$4=6,SUMIFS(Name6,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),IF($D$4=7,SUMIFS(Name7,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),SUMIFS(Name8,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75)))),IF($D$4=9,SUMIFS(Name9,Nmd1,189,Nmd2,'Spreadsheet '!$A75),IF($D$4=10,SUMIFS(Name10,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),IF($D$4=11,SUMIFS(Name11,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75),SUMIFS(Name12,Nmd1,189,Nmd2, ‘Spreadsheet '!$A75))))))
```

`Name1` to `Name12` are different named columns full of numeric values.

`Nmd1` is a named range that is full of numeric values

`Nmd2` is a named range that is full of numeric values

**$A75** contains a numeric value (fixed and not affected by the data pull down)

All of these are based upon a pivot that pulls live data from a database, so the formula needs to work with this constraint.

This is an excerpt from cell **H12**, from the sheet that contains all of the named ranges above.

```
=+'DATA PULL DOWN FROM SYSTEM'!H12
```

**Question**:

My challenge is that I need to change all of the 189 figures to greater to 200 (`">=200"`) and less than 300 (`"<300"`). I have tried to involve the following array `{">=200","<300"}`, but have not managed to get this working with all the criteria.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Neil, have you tried splitting your big problem into smaller parts? This will take far less time for everyone. e.g., if you want to change 189 figures, please show us how you change one. What have you tried and how did it shows not to work?

Comment: Hi J. Chomel - thank you. It has already been split out (my first formula exceed the c.8,200 character limit...). The following works as a standalone, but not in the wider formula SUM(SUMIFS(Name1,Nmd1,{">=200","<300"})*{1,-1})

Comment: I still don't get what's wrong. Have you tried using *find/replace* in a text editor to edit the formula? If the formula becomes too large after the replacement, then this is your problem, but it is very difficult to understand it is from your question. That's why I advise you split your problem in smaller pieces, the current one being "What should I do if my formula is too length for Excel?". Then you can describe how you got there - what you did great

Comment: Okay J. Chomel, please let me try and clarify. in Nmd2 there are multiple values. The lowest is 109 and the highest is 663. The formula that works selects a specific value of 189. The new formula needs to return the values of all of the numbers between 200 and 300. There are only the following values in this range - 201, 202, 203, 211,  212, 221, 222, 249, 259, 269. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is too complicated for me like that. What you need is try to have a small example on which we can help you. Not an example involving a 800 chars formula! And you say you *did not manage*, but what happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: Thank you for your help J. Chomel. I will keep trying to crack it (and will post solution if I manage). I had an error message saying detailing the c.8,200 character limit of formulas (will try and reproduce and post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is having exceeded the **`8192`** [Excel limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for formula length, then here is what you should do:

[`189`] are 3 chars, and [`">=200","<300"})*{1,-1}`] are 23 chars. So you must find 20 chars per instance of [`189`] in your formula. First you could try renaming `Spreadsheet` to `S`, then `Name1`/`Name2`/`Name3`/... to `N1`/`N2`/`N3`/..., `Nmd1`/`Nmd2`/`Nmd3`/... to `d1`/`d2`/`d3`/...

Another option for you is to learn Excel [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), and have a program do it. I think it would be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Hi J. Chomel, thank you for all your help on this one. In the end I had to introduce a new column that removed the need seek a range between 200 and 300. It is a less elegant workaround then hoped.